# Laravel appended attribute for returning next notifiable datetime with Carbon PHP

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I'm working within a Laravel 10 project that's using Carbon PHP 2.68.*. I need to calculate the next available notifiable datetime for the user based on their preferences:

- Days of week, 1 through to 7
- Time slot
- Prefers time sensitivity

My attribute `getNextNotifiableDatetimeAttribute` is mostly working apart from the day of the week. Here's an example of the problem:

If my available days are: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7. If the current day is Monday (1) and I uncheck Monday, the next available day should be Tuesday (2) but it's giving me a combination of Wednesday / Thursday.

How can I ensure to always get the next available datetime in this foreach loop:

```php
/**
 * Get the next notifiable datetime based on configured setup
 */
public function getNextNotifiableDatetimeAttribute(): string
{
    $now = Carbon::now('UTC');
    $notifiableDays = $this->notify_on_days;

    // if on holiday, return next date as on_holiday_until
    if ($this->on_holiday_until && $this->on_holiday_until > $now) {
        return Carbon::parse($this->on_holiday_until)->toDateTimeString();
    }

    // If the user wants to be notified on the current day, and the current time is within the time slot, return the current datetime.
    if (in_array($now->dayOfWeek, $notifiableDays) && $this->isWithinTimeSlot($now)) {
        return $now->toDateTimeString();
    }

    // Find the next available day of the week to notify the user.
    $nextNotifyDay = null;
    foreach ($notifiableDays as $day) {
        if ($day == $now->dayOfWeek) {
            $nextNotifyDay = 0;
            break;
        }

        if ($day > $now->dayOfWeek) {
            $nextNotifyDay = $day;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If no day is found in the current week, take the first day from the next week.
    if ($nextNotifyDay === null) {
        $nextNotifyDay = reset($notifiableDays);
    }

    // Calculate the next notifiable datetime based on the next available day and the time slot.
    $nextNotifyDatetime = Carbon::createMidnightDate(
        $now->year,
        $now->month,
        $now->day
    )->addDays($nextNotifyDay);

    if (!$this->isWithinTimeSlot($nextNotifyDatetime)) {
        $nextNotifyDatetime = $this->setToNextAvailableTime($nextNotifyDatetime);
    }

    return $nextNotifyDatetime->toDateTimeString();
}

/**
 * Check if the given datetime is within the user's time slot.
 *
 * @param  Carbon\Carbon  $datetime
 * @return bool
 */
private function isWithinTimeSlot(Carbon $datetime): bool
{
    // if the user has time-sensitive notifications enabled then we should
    // disregard the time slot.
    if ($this->prefers_time_sensitive_notifications) {
        return true;
    }

    switch ($this->notify_time_slot) {
        case 'anytime':
            // anytime will notify regardless of current time
            return true;
        case 'morning':
            return $datetime->hour >= 6 && $datetime->hour < 12;
        case 'afternoon':
            return $datetime->hour >= 12 && $datetime->hour < 18;
        case 'evening':
            return $datetime->hour >= 18 && $datetime->hour < 23;
        case 'daytime':
            return $datetime->hour >= 9 && $datetime->hour < 18;
        default:
            // Handle additional time slots as needed.
            return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Set the given datetime to the next available time slot.
 *
 * @param  Carbon\Carbon  $datetime
 * @return Carbon\Carbon
 */
private function setToNextAvailableTime(Carbon $datetime): Carbon
{
    switch ($this->notify_time_slot) {
        case 'morning':
            return $datetime->setHour(6)->setMinute(0)->setSecond(0);
        case 'afternoon':
            return $datetime->setHour(12)->setMinute(0)->setSecond(0);
        case 'evening':
            return $datetime->setHour(18)->setMinute(0)->setSecond(0);
        case 'daytime':
            return $datetime->addDay()->setHour(9)->setMinute(0)->setSecond(0);
        default:
            // Handle additional time slots as needed.
            return $datetime;
    }
}
```

This part in particular returns the wrong number as per my above example:

```php
// Find the next available day of the week to notify the user.
$nextNotifyDay = null;
foreach ($notifiableDays as $day) {
    if ($day == $now->dayOfWeek) {
        $nextNotifyDay = 0;
        break;
    }

    if ($day > $now->dayOfWeek) {
        $nextNotifyDay = $day;
        break;
    }
}

// If no day is found in the current week, take the first day from the next week.
if ($nextNotifyDay === null) {
    $nextNotifyDay = reset($notifiableDays);
}
```

Comment: Better [mre] the last part providing your "test" data. It's pretty convoluted for the large code above and the broad description. So a bit more description of the actual types and what the iterators foreach over in the smaller segment could also help to get better feedback if not even an answer that is not guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Using continue instead of break in the 1st condition of your 2nd code chunk would always get the next available day after the current day..

```
if ($day == $now->dayOfWeek) {
    // If the current day is in the notifiableDays array, skip and move to the next day.
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Which part exactly please?

Comment: 1st if condition of the "This part in particular returns the wrong number as per my above example:" part.